# Productivity Power Tools on VS 2010 Express for Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, productivity-power-tools

Is there a way to install the Productivity Power Tools on Visual Studio Express (for Windows Phone) ? I downloaded the extension there: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/ but when I try to install the extension I get this error:

```
This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot install extensions on Visual Studio Express (With the exception of [NuGet](http://nuget.org).

Buy Visual Studio Professional if you wish to get the full experience of Visual Studio.